# How to make a sticky footer in Bootstrap?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, sticky-footer

I am currently developing a **Django** project and I want to set up a footer pasted at the bottom of the page (sticky footer).

looking for forums, I found a solution that 'does the job' (ie paste the footer at the bottom of page) but has an awkward behavior to know that depending on the size of the screen it masks some buttons (for example, the paging button of a **dataTable**)

it is also embarrassing for my functional tests (selenium) because some tests fail when the butters are masked by the footer (see image in the red box)

Is there a bootstrap footer or a way to overcome this problem?

[image]

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

.asteriskField{
  display: none;
}
form .alert ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
form .alert ul {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
body > div > div.col-6 > div > div > h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  /*background-color: red;*/

}
```

Comment: provide some html code for it (whole of the code if possible)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a django developer (as you tagged this question with `django`, which is not really related), so don't blame me if this is not exactly what you want:

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 56px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.page_con_wrap {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
}

footer {
  background: #252429;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!--Navigation Start-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <!-- Navbar links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--Navigation End-->

  <!--Page Content Start-->
  <div class="page_con_wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Page Content End-->

  <!--Footer Content Start-->
  <footer>
    <div class="text-center">Copyright @2019 All rights reserved</div>
  </footer>
  <!--Footer Content End-->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        .bottom {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 30px; 
        }
    </style>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: yellow;>
        <div class=" container-fluid" ">
                <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
                <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
                <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
                <div class=" row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Responsive Columns</h1>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
        <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 576px wide.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-3</div>
            <pre>                                   </pre>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">


        <div>© 2018 Copyright:
            <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
        </div>


    </div>




    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/yrogfwma/

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a Django problem.

Check this official example from bootstrap it might help:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer/